# Datetime Nullable value c# winforms

Tags: winforms, datetime, null, nullable

I have checkbox and if checkbox checked is true , i want to insert textbox text as datetime(no problem here)However if checkbox checked is not true , i want to give null datetime value.

I don't know how can i give null datetime **during inserting** data ?

```
context.SP_INSERT_DATA(MY_CHECKBOX.Checked == true ? Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox.Text) : NULLABLE_value , CustomerID);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.SP_INSERT_DATA(MY_CHECKBOX.Checked == true ? Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox.Text) : (DateTime?)null , CustomerID);
```